# Yes or no toggle or slider

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a slider or a toggle for my application that allows the user to select yes or no and its harder then i thought to track one down...

I found this [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemax) but its 1 or 2 numeric and not yes or no text...any suggestions

Comment: Wait, what? Why doesn't a check box work, again?

Comment: @Matchu - Maybe there's a "maybe" in the middle? :)

Comment: Maybe style a checkbox?... something like this: http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we could edit it to have something like this,

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider-range-max").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value?'Yes':'No');
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value")?'Yes':'No');
});​
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmLcw/)

Comment: How do you make the demo "go both ways?"  xD

Comment: He means you need a third setting in the middle for Bi

Comment: @Matt - look at Theming tab in [jqueryui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)

Comment: @Reigel - Hahaha.  Excellent.