# Jquery slider allocate label words to values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

This is a bit like the problem posted here: [Yes or no toggle or slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903147/yes-or-no-toggle-or-slider) - but i can't get the solution to work in this example.

I have a horizontal incremental range slider which i would like to modify so that the labels are decoded to small - medium - large for values 1 - 2 - 3

I've tried sticking an array to decode but i just can't get it to work right.

Here's what i have so far:

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1,
                max: 3,
                step: 1,
                values: [ 2, 3 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                }
            });
            $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
        });
    </script>
```

so that if positions 2 - 3 were selected (as is the default), the label would read 'medium - large'.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: ok - i think i got it by doing:
["small","medium","large"][ui.values[ 0 ]-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What about this?

It uses a mapper object instead of an array but also includes a function that returns a string instead of creating it yourself:

```
$(function() {

    // mapper    
    var valueMap = {
        1 : "small",
        2 : "medium",
        3 : "large",
        getText : function(arr) {
            return this[arr[0]] + " - " + this[arr[1]];
        }
    };

    // initial range slider values
    var initial = [2, 3];

    // initialize slider
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 3,
        step: 1,
        values: initial,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#amount").val(valueMap.getText(ui.values));
        }
    });

    // initialize value display
    $("#amount").val(valueMap.getText(initial));

});
```